# Using SplObjectStorage as a data map, can you use a mutable array as the data?

Tags: php, spl, arrayaccess, splobjectstorage

In the following code:

```
$storage = new \SplObjectStorage();

$fooA = new \StdClass();
$fooB = new \StdClass();

$storage[$fooA] = 1;
$storage[$fooB] = array();

$storage[$fooA] = 2;
$storage[$fooB][] = 'test';
```

I would expect `$storage[$fooA]` to be `1`, which it is. I would also expect `$storage[$fooB]` to be `array('test')`, which it is not. This also triggers a notice that reads, "Indirect modification of overloaded element of SplObjectStorage has no effect in..."

I think this happens because the implementation of `ArrayAccess` in `SplObjectStorage` doesn't return values by reference.

Is there any way to use `SplObjectStorage` as a data map where keys are objects and values are mutable arrays? Are there any other viable options for doing this kind of work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indirect modification (i.e. `offsetGet` returning a reference) is a recent ability. See [the note for `ArrayAccess::offsetGet`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayaccess.offsetget.php). It doesn't seem that SplObjectStorage makes use of it (yet?).

I suggest you use direct modification instead:

```
$a = $storage[$fooB];
$a[] = 'test';
$storage[$fooB] = $a;
```